# Contribution Status Edit in Options Group

Tags: contributions

The set of Contribution Status are available in the Options Group and allowed for Edit, though it seems that it is just for the names of the respective Contribution Status.  What should be considered when changing these names ?  For example, if I need a contribution status of "Waived", can i just rename the existing status of "Cancelled" ?  I looked around and there seems to be concerns in adding/changing of contribution status as they are connected to account rules of the contribution.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the intention of 'Waived"? just wondering if you would be better tackling this via another approach

Comment: Thanks.  'Waived' will be used if someone is given the privilege of attending the event without the need to pay for it.  This could be a staff where it is still important to register her participation but her payment is recorded as waived and hence no amount is collected.

Comment: sounds to me like there should be no contribution record at all in that case

Comment: Based on your comment above, I would recommend using CiviDiscount, and generating a 100% discount code for your staff members. You could control potential gaming by limiting the # of uses. It will zero out the price point, and the Fee level on the event registration will also include a mention of the discount so it'll be easy to spot them if that's what you need. Now, if you absolutely must have a Waived contribution status, I'd pick one you know 100% your system never uses, e.g. in our case that's "Chargeback".

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure I would add a new contribution status rather then meddle with the existing ones. But maybe that is just being to careful :-)

Comment: Thanks Erik, how can you add a Contribution Status? i wasn't able to find out how to do that.

Comment: Yeah the interface says "This option group is reserved for system use. You cannot add or delete options in this list."

Comment: Allrighty, I was not aware of this. Shows you how many times I had to add a contribution status.....I think you can change the label of the Cancelled one, alternative might be to use Word Replacements? See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#using-word-replacement-to-change-terminology